# What font is used on the Google maps for the labels?

Tags: google-maps, fonts

What font is used on the Google maps for the labels?

Comment: [2018] Product Sans : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_Sans

Comment: @stallingOne Are you sure? My browser, at least, still uses Roboto for the labels. One of the clearer differences is in the capital Q, where in Product Sans, the majority of the tail is inside the bowl, while Roboto leaves the entire tail on the outside.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arial is the base font, but then they outline it very deliberately to make it stand out against certain backgrounds.

http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/9318b651e7174aa0?pli=1

This is an extremely good analysis of the textual design of the maps, which may also address your question: (assuming your question is motivated by "why is the font so effective"):

http://www.41latitude.com/post/3183269217/google-maps-label-reability-3

**EDIT**: I posted the wrong blog entry for 411latitude at first, but I've corrected it now.

Comment: Any Idea how can I reach the same outlining effect using html and css?

Answer (score 10):

Google Maps now uses [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) for labels.

Comment: Hello, can you provide a link to confirm that the font has been changed?

Comment: When using the Google Maps API, they add a CSS link to the <head> of your document to load Roboto.