# Change the font-family of Google Maps labels?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

I'm making a custom Google Map, using the official [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html).

However, it doesn't seem to be possible to change the font-family of the labels (which is [Arial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270362/what-font-is-used-on-the-google-maps-for-the-labels)).

Does anyone know if this is possible in Google Maps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is: it can't be done. The best you can do is switch off all Google Maps labels, and use custom overlays.

Alternatively, make your own tiles using a service like Cloudmade or TileMill.

Answer (score 11):

(**EDIT**: I now see the original question was about native Google Map labels, not custom Marker Labels. For my original response i.e. a custom font-family on Marker Labels, please read on...)

**Fast forward to 2018...**

If you call the Google Maps API, you can use a custom Google Font. Here is the [documentation on font-family](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerLabel.fontFamily).

You‘ll need to specify the `fontFamily` option of the `label` option when creating a new google.maps.Marker. I used a font from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), eg:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: posiiton,
    map: map,
    label: {
        text: 'Label text',
        fontFamily: "'Domine', serif",
    }
});
```

Comment: It works :-) +1 for removing the green checkmark form the previous post

Comment: Is this for the native Google Maps labels ? or just markers

Comment: Honestly I can't remember the difference, but here's a fiddle adapted from Google's default example which shows a simple marker label with a custom font: https://jsfiddle.net/cuka/bhtwL1rv/